# Multiple Date Form Element in Drupal 9

Tags: drupal-8, drupal-forms, drupal-9, drupal-field-api

I am trying to add a multiple date field (unlimited cardinality) in my custom module configuration form.

```
$form['holidayForm']['holidays'] = [
        '#type' => 'date',
        '#multiple' => TRUE,
        '#title' => $this->t('Holidays'),
        '#default_value' => $config->get('holidayForm.holidays'),
    ];
```

As you can see, I have added the #multiple property but I still get a single field

[image]

Is there a different property that I needed to add.

Comment: The `#multiple` property allows the user to select multiple options and is available only for `select` input type, it's not implemented by the `date` form element.

Comment: How I can allow the user to add multiple date fields?